# Rails I18n translation missing despite being defined in en.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'm trying to render text in a view:

`<h3><%= I18n.t('product.project_summary.exception_details') %></h3>`

And my `en.yml` file is like this:

```
en:
  product:
    project_summary:
      exception_details: "Exception Details"
```

I checked my spaces and indentation in the `en.yml` file, and everything looked good. But, it still renders as `translation missing: en.product.project_summary.exception_details`.

Comment: Is that your full `en.yml` content?  Do you have `en` key?

Comment: @Jack did you check the `config.i18n.load_path` in the `application.rb` does it define the path of where your `en.yml` are placed?